# "git add -A" command

Tags: git

does this "git add -A" command really add newly created, modified and deleted to the staging area in git repo all at once?

if so, is it a good practice for developers for staging files using this command, especially
in case, one has no need to ignore some file change in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a proper `.gitignore` file and any file that is added to the repo may have to be tracked, you can use `git add -A`. If you are not sure if there are files in the working directory that should not be added to the repo, use `git add -u`

Answer (score -3):

Typically I wouldn't suggest using it, but it has its place.

It's handy if you know you want to add all changes in the working copy including deletes. However with commands like that it's very easy to add changes you didn't know about.

Large change set that you 100% sure about, it's pretty handy, just make sure you start with a clean working copy.

Comment: In future, it would be to not only the community's benefit but also to your own if you edit your answer to clarify it rather than do it in the comments. I have done this for you for now.